# How to make python count to full number

Tags: python

I dont know how to make python to count to full number since its counting from 0, heres my code:

```
import requests
import time
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init(convert=True)

times = int(input('How many x: '))


for i in range(times):
  print(Fore.GREEN + '{}/{} entered'.format(i, times))
```

So for example if times = 10 it will count from 0 to 9, how can i change that so it would count to 10?

Comment: `for i in range(times+1):`

Comment: just add a 1 to it

Comment: `range(x)` stops before it reaches x.

Comment: or `for i in range(1, times + 1)` if you want 1-10 when 10 in the number entered

Comment: @zzex `range(1, times+1)` as I mentioned above

Comment: Thanks guys, solved, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to count from 1-10 instead of 0-9, just add 1 to the `start` and `stop` parameters

```
for i in range(1, times + 1):
    # ....
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range(x)` method goes from 0 to `x - 1`.

So, just add 1 to `times` in your for loop.

```
for i in range(times + 1):
    print(Fore.GREEN + '{}/{} entered'.format(i, times))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use i+1 when you format:

```
for i in range(times):
    print(Fore.GREEN + '{}/{} entered'.format(i+1, times))
```